# Adding a new folder/item does not appear in target DB when published via workflow

Tags: workflow

Added a new folder and item in it with WorkFlow and published it via workflow, but it doesn't appear in the next level db. Any thoughts

Master db:

[image]

Preview db: missing the test folder and content

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100280/discussion-on-question-by-sai-sitecore-new-folder-and-item-when-published-via-wo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default sitecore workflow doesnt publish the parent folder. We need to first publish the folder and then the WF Item.

As its not a good practice to have WF to the folder, we have written a pipeline which is triggered in the sitecore publish event(publish:itemProcessed), so whenever an item is published this method checks to see if the item exists in the next environment and the folder path matches, if in any of those cases fail this method will go ahead and publish the folder or move the file path accordingly.